# Setting a scale

Tags: qgis, cartography, print-composer, printing, scale

Is there a way of adding a map to a layout in print composer at a fixed scale for example `1:1000`? I can set the scale in the project but it doesn't seem to carry through to the print composer.

Comment: look at this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i6G9H6n1-Bo it works from qgis lyon and more recent versions. The tip for a fixed scale is in the first minute of the video

Answer (score 3):

In the print composer, you would select the map, then choose item property and set the scale there

[image]